# Calculate days between occurrences

Tags: excel, function

I have a water tank and I record dates of rainfall and usage.

```
**Event**       **Date**
Measurement     28 April 2019
Rainfall        29 April 2019
Measurement     2 May 2019
Rainfall        3 May 2019
Rainfall        3 May 2019
Usage       7 May 2019
Rainfall        8 May 2019
Rainfall        9 May 2019
Usage       9 May 2019
Rainfall        10 May 2019
Usage       11 May 2019
```

I want to create a new column that gives the number of days since last event. So on the 10th May row of the rainfall, the result would be "1" as the previous "Rainfall" event was on the 9th May

Comment: You can do this with simple subtraction, and format the column as a number instead of a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to sort your data, add this formula ...

```
=IFERROR(IF(A3="Rainfall",B3 - INDIRECT("B" & MAX(IF($A$1:A2="Rainfall",ROW($A$1:A2),-1))),""),"")
```

... to cell `C3` and fill down.

Take note, this is an array formula so you need to apply it by pressing **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Skin, worked perfectly. Sorry for the late reply

Comment: @Leon cool man, you may want to flag it as the answer. Thanks